# How to add vendored crates to project workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

in my rust project, i run `cargo vendor` and vendored all dependencies in `vendor` folder. The `.cargo/config.toml` file is updated to point to `vendor/` folder.

```
[source.vendored-sources]
directory = "vendor"
```

Some of the vendored crates i have patched, so they are moved from vendor to patch folder, and `Cargo.toml` is updated as

```
[patch.crates-io]  
patched-crate = {path = "patch/patched-crate"}
```

All builds fine, and runs fine.

I use `nvim` + `rust-analyser`, with appropriate plugins. When i open a file from patched crate, `rust-analyzer` complains that it cannot read metadata of the patched crate.
It also gives a solution that it can be fixed by adding the patched crate to the workspace in `Cargo.toml`

```
LSP[rust_analyzer] rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file /home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/patch/hyper-openssl/Cargo.toml, cargo 1.58.0 (f01b232bc 2022-01-19): Failed to run `
"cargo" "metadata" "--format-version" "1" "--manifest-path" "/home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/patch/hyper-openssl/Cargo.toml" "--filter-platform" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: curren
t package believes it's in a workspace when it's not:
current:   /home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/patch/hyper-openssl/Cargo.toml
workspace: /home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/Cargo.toml
this may be fixable by adding `patch/hyper-openssl` to the `workspace.members` array of the manifest located at: /home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/Cargo.toml
Alternatively, to keep it out of the workspace, add the package to the `workspace.exclude` array, or add an empty `[workspace]` table to the package's manifest.
```

When i add the patched crate to workspace

```
[workspace]
members = [
  ".",
  "lib/crate1",
  "lib/crate2",
  "patch/*",
  "vendor/*".
]
```

i get build errors that it cannot load manifest of the vendored crate

```
cargo build --release --no-default-features --features ocp-logging
error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/vendor/azure_storage`
```

**Edit 1**

As suggested in a comment, I updated `Cargo.toml` with only the patch directories. And when i open in it nvim, i get error

```
LSP[rust_analyzer] rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file /home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/Cargo.toml, cargo 1.58.0 (f01b232bc 2022-01-19): Failed to run `"cargo" "metadata" "
--format-version" "1" "--manifest-path" "/home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/Cargo.toml" "--filter-platform" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: failed to select a version for the requirement
 `hyper-rustls = "^0.23.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.22.1
location searched: directory source `/home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/vendor` (which is replacing registry `crates-io`)
required by package `aws-config v0.9.0 (/home/vimalkum/src/vector-collector/vector/patch/aws-config)`
perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?
```

but `vendor` folder contains `hyper-rustls` version `version = "0.22.1"`

Comment: Have you tried removing `"vendor/*"` from the list, but leaving `"patch/*"`?

Comment: @PitaJ i tried, but still getting error. updated the question

Comment: So something is requiring `hyper-rustls = "^0.23.0"` but you have version `0.22.1` vendored. Have you tried vendoring the newer version instead?